# Create index with mongodb C Driver

Tags: c, mongodb, indexing

I can create index in mongodb via mongodb shell

**i.e.** `db['test'].ensureIndex( { fieldname:1 } )`

But how to create the same index with mongo-c-driver?
    Who could point me out? thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

If you have a set of documents with keys as `name` and `age`

You can create indices like this:

```
static void tutorial_index( mongo_connection *conn ) {
  bson key[1];

  bson_init( key );
  bson_append_int( key, "name", 1 );
  bson_finish( key );

  mongo_create_index( conn, "tutorial.persons", key, 0, NULL );

  bson_destroy( key );

  printf( "simple index created on \"name\"\n" );

  bson_init( key );
  bson_append_int( key, "age", 1 );
  bson_append_int( key, "name", 1 );
  bson_finish( key );

  mongo_create_index( conn, "tutorial.persons", key, 0, NULL );

  bson_destroy( key );

  printf( "compound index created on \"age\", \"name\"\n" );
}
```

Reference:
[MongoDB Reference](http://api.mongodb.org/c/0.4/tutorial.html)